# what is the difference between *(arr+1)+1 and (*(arr+1))+1 in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have recently been studying 2 D arrays at school in C++ and I have studied pointers as well. But this is confusing me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    char arr[][6]={"Name1","Name2"};
    cout<<*(arr+1)+1<<endl;
    cout<<(*(arr+1))+1<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

And the output that I get is:

```
ame2
ame2
```

I have been taught that the `*` operator has a lower precedence than the `+` operator. Then why is `*(arr+1)+1` and `(*(arr+1))+1` giving the same output? Aren't they processed differently by C++?

Comment: You've been taught wrong: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: The unary operator `*` has a higher precedence than binary operator `+`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for details.

Comment: And *because* `*` is higher, they give the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, many of my friends have asked me the same(or similar) questions as well. So here's what I do to solve such questions. Instead of calling '*' a dereferencing operator I call it an "value at address" operator.

writing name of an array gives us the base address of an array. So writing `*(arr+1)+1`
is actually **value at address(arr + 1) + 1**
Lets assume that arr is an integer array and starts at location 1000. That being said our equation resolves to **value at address(1000 + 1) + 1**

Now remember that incrementing a pointer is not same as incrementing an integer. Why?

```
int i=1000;
i++; //i will now be 1000 + 1
int *p=&i; //p points to 1000
p++; //p now points to 1000 + sizeof(int) ie 1000 + 4 = 1004
```

Getting back to where we were. **value at address(1000 + 1) + 1** now resolves to **value at address(1004) + 1**, which further resolves to **value at address 1008**.

Try performing the same on (*(arr+1))+1, we get  **(value at address(1000+1)+1)** which resolves to **(value at address(1004)+1)** which further resolves to **(value at address(1008))**, which is similar to our previous result. Now you can simply replace the entire fuss with whatever value the 1008 address has. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This explains it to me perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you also tell me why is "ame2" coming as output even though I am pointing to only one address location(as in your example is 1008). Should it not print only "a"?

Comment: That's because when you point to a character array and fires a print function, a printf or cout, it starts printing all the stuff until it finds a null character i.e '\0'. But that's not the case with an int array.

Answer (score 3):

No, the pointer dereference operator has higher priority than the addition operator, so `*(arr+1)+1` and  `(*(arr+1))+1` are the same.